# Custom Script Editor

Tags: java, string, performance, syntax

I'm making my own *script editor* (in this case for `Arma: Cold War Assault`) because I want to learn and this is challenging enough.

Let me just get this out of the way: ***please don't tell me that I should do easier things. I want to do this anyway***.

So, basically I have the simple GUI for now with a working new/open/save file menu.

I've managed to highlight certain words with different colors (because I want to tackle the hardest part first) but it's **not efficient**.

I've come up with several ideas for the algorithm (didn't implement them all), but I want to know what you'do, if there's a certain way and what I am doing wrong.

This all happens inside a `JTextPane` class.

---

The arrays containing the reserved words:

```
Collections.addAll(keywords, "private", "public", "if", "not", "then", "else", "else if");          
Collections.addAll(operators, "+", "-", "=", "==", "?", "!","(", ")","{", "}", "_", "-", "^", "<", ">");            

ArrayList<String> keywords = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> operators = new ArrayList<String>();
```

---

Everytime the user makes an update to the document, it get's updated:

```
@Override
public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
    update();
}

@Override
public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
    update();
}
```

---

When the user stops typing, it waits 500 ms to update the screen:

```
Timer t;

/**
 * Updates the text when user stops typing
 */
public void update(){
    if (t != null) {
        if (t.isRunning())
            t.stop();
    }

    t = new Timer(500, new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();    

            String text = getText();
            int length = text.length();

            SimpleAttributeSet attrs = new SimpleAttributeSet();
            StyleConstants.setForeground(attrs, Color.BLACK);
            StyledDocument doc = getStyledDocument();       
            doc.setCharacterAttributes(0, length, attrs, true);

            int c = 0, carriage = 0;

            while ( (c < length ) ){                            

                if(text.codePointAt(c) == 10){
                    carriage += 1;
                }
                for (String s : keywords) {
                    if (text.startsWith(s, c)) {
                        StyleConstants.setForeground(attrs, Color.blue);
                        doc.setCharacterAttributes(
                                c - carriage, s.length(), attrs, false);
                    }
                }

                for (String s : operators) {
                    if (text.startsWith(s, c)) {
                        StyleConstants.setForeground(attrs, Color.red);
                        doc.setCharacterAttributes(
                                c - carriage, s.length(), attrs, false);
                    }
                }   

                c++;
            }                   
            System.out.println("Iterations took: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + " ms");
            t.stop();
        }
    });
    t.start();
}
```

How would I go about doing this more efficiently?

[image]

Comment: If you're looking for someone to review your code (to make it more efficient) you may want to try [codereview.se]. You'll have to clarify if you're looking for something else.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know about that web page. I've submitted my code there.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/161871/Fast-Colored-TextBox-for-syntax-highlighting

It looks like you want 'idea[s] for [an] algorithm.' Therefore, the difference in language should not matter much.

Comment: Thank. I will look into it, but JAVA has so many classes that do many different things that I get lost. There are like 3 or 4 classes for String reading i think. It's very confusing. I'm trying to compare hashCodes instead of string to string, but I don't know how to get the hashCode from the text and know at wich point that word appeared. I don't even know if I'm coloring the text right! I just used an example I got from another answer here. Maybe there are better ways.